# Sub-gamma and gaussian

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be identically distributed independent random variables such that $P\{|X_i| \geq u\} \leq e^{–u^p}$ for some $p \geq 1$. Let $q = p/(p-1)$ be the conjugate of $p$. Let $s = (s_1, \ldots , s_n) ∈ R^n$. Let $Z = \sum^n_{i=1} s_iX_i$. Prove that there exists a constant $L$ (that depends on $p$ but not on $n$) such that

$$P\{Z \geq t\} \leq L\exp\left(-\frac{1}{L}\min\left\{\frac{t^2}{\|s\|_2^2},\frac{t^p}{\|s\|_q^p}\right\}\right)$$
where $\|s\|_p^p =\begin{cases}\sum^n_{i=1} |s_i|^p &(\text{if } \ p < \infty) \\ \max_i |s_i| &(\text{if } \ p = \infty)\end{cases}$.

Can someone give me a hint to prove this exercise?